# How to limit the network bandwidth usage in Virtual box

Tags: 16.04, virtualbox, bandwidth, upload

I am using `Virtual box 5.1.22` on `Ubuntu 16.04`. I need to limit the bandwidth of the Internet connection (more precisely the upload speed) being used by an application running on `Windows 7`(a Virtual machine) in `Virtual box`. Is there a way to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix it inside `Windows 7` (inside the virtual machine) by installing [netlimiter](https://www.netlimiter.com/download) and adding a new rule to the application limiting its upload speed. This solution will work on all `Windows` above `Windows 7`